# Bulk convert XML to JSON with particular output

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, xml, bluebird

How do I convert approximately 3000 XML files into JSON files using node?

I've been able to get a script below to a single XML to JSON file in the format that I want, and I've been attempting to promisify the script using bluebird, but I keep getting errors. I've been able to get the script below to list the filenames, but then I get the error "Unhandled rejection Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'journal-article-10.2307_357359.xml'"

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = require('fs');
var convert = require('xml-js');

fs.readdirAsync = function(dirname) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readdir(dirname, function(err, filenames){
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            else
                resolve(filenames);
        });
    });
};

fs.readFileAsync = function(filename, enc) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(filename, enc, function(err, data){
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            else
                resolve(data);
        });
    });
};

function getFile(filename) {
    return fs.readFileAsync(filename, 'utf8');
}

fs.readdirAsync('./metadata/').then(function (filenames){
    console.log(filenames);
    return Promise.all(filenames.map(getFile));
}).then(function (files){
  files.forEach(function(files){
    function nativeType(value) {
      var nValue = Number(value);
      if (!isNaN(nValue)) {
        return nValue;
      }
      var bValue = value.toLowerCase();
      if (bValue === 'true') {
        return true;
      } else if (bValue === 'false') {
        return false;
      }
      return value;
    }
    var removeJsonTextAttribute = function(value, parentElement) {
      try {
        var keyNo = Object.keys(parentElement._parent).length;
        var keyName = Object.keys(parentElement._parent)[keyNo - 1];
        parentElement._parent[keyName] = nativeType(value);
      } catch (e) {}
    };
    var options = {
      compact: true,
      trim: true,
      ignoreDeclaration: true,
      ignoreInstruction: true,
      ignoreAttributes: true,
      ignoreComment: true,
      ignoreCdata: true,
      ignoreDoctype: true,
      textFn: removeJsonTextAttribute,
      spaces: 2
    };
    fs.writeFile("./json/" + fileaname + ".json", convert.xml2json(options));
  });
});
```

I would like to be able to convert the entire folder of XML files to JSON (to upload to couchDB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ENOENT` is a standard POSIX error code that means the path to the file is not found. You've tried to open the name of a file or directory that doesn't exist. In this case, `fs.readdir` returns names that are not fully qualified file names, so you'll need to prefix them with the path that you gave it, specifically: `'./metadata/'`. The error message that you're seeing tells you the file that was opened: `journal-article-10.2307_357359.xml`, but in this case, you probably want to open `./metadata/journal-article-10.2307_357359.xml`.

You can see this with the following simple example:

```
# Create a dummy directory named `garbage` that contains only 3 entries
$ mkdir -p garbage/{foo,bar,baz}
# Run `node` interactively
$ node
> const fs = require('fs');
undefined
> fs.readdirSync('./garbage')
[ 'bar', 'baz', 'foo' ]
```

It doesn't make sense to open `'bar'` since that doesn't exist. You'll need to open `'./garbage/bar'` for it to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Learning node.js and just couldn't figure this problem out.